# Is there anyway to mark images as spoiler?

Tags: discord.js

The new discord update added the feature to mark images and text as spoilers for text: you just have to type `|| text ||`. For images, there is a check mark at the bottom of the attachment prompt:

[image: Attachment propmt]

Is there a way to mark images as spoiler or is the feature too new?

This does not work:

```js
let image = new Attachment('./img/image.jpg'); 
message.channel.send("|| " + image + " ||");`
```

Comment: I think the spoiler feature is still to new (it's only been out for like a day). I'm guessing it'll take a couple of days before that feature is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    message.channel.send({
        files: [{
          attachment: 'IMG LINK',
          name: 'SPOILER_NAME.jpg'
        }]
      })
```

Answer (score 4):

a quick way of doing it would be starting the filename with SPOILER_
for example `img.png` would become `SPOILER_img.png`

Comment: that would just make the client look for a file named SPOILER_img.png

Comment: any files with SPOILER_ in front, becomes an automatic spoiler so therefore image naming should be named on whether Spoiler is wanted or not, file-system will rename if needed.

Comment: excuse me I didn't try it properly yes this works my mistake I really apologise

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO6nV.png) is what the [API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits) has listed for the image for embeds and it doesn't seem to mention marking as a spoiler so perhaps it is yet to be added for bots. I can't find anything about spoilers in the API, maybe you'll have more luck.