# Discord.js embed image spoiler

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that sends embeds. Sometimes I send embeds with a picture, but I want to put a spoiler over it. Is that possible? The problem is that I get the image from a link, so I can't rename it to 'SPOILER_'. Downloading the image and renaming it would be very troublesome, there must be another way. This is how the code I insert the image with:

```
{
  "embed": {
    "image": {
      "url": url
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to mark images as spoiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54476198/is-there-anyway-to-mark-images-as-spoiler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Unfortunately, this is not possible via renaming the image file with `SPOILER_`**

Taken from the [docs](https://discord.js.org/), with [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) you're able to fetch an image, rename it and then send it in an embed, like so:

```js
channel.send({
  embed: {
    image: {
         url: "attachment://SPOILER_FILE.jpg"
      }
   },
   files: [{
      attachment: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/05/18/28/cute-3293750_960_720.jpg",
      name: "SPOILER_FILE.jpg"
   }]
});
```

But if you test this out, the image will still be visible.
[image: Test Spoiler Image on Embed]

However, if you remove the embed part of the message, it works:

```js
channel.send({
   files: [{
      attachment: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/04/05/18/28/cute-3293750_960_720.jpg",
      name: "SPOILER_FILE.jpg"
   }]
});
```

[image: Test Spoiler Image on Normal Message]

---

**So what now?**

Give them feedback: upvote and comment on [this](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360043419812-Ability-to-mark-as-spoiler-images-in-rich-embeds) suggestion and other places to let them know, and hopefully they'll add it soon.